# when calling the getcostandusage operation: user not enabled for cost explorer access on lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cost-explorer

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the getcostandusage operation: user not enabled for cost explorer access on lambda function..

Getting this issue when using this code and also attach all required policies to the lambda function role. Any solution?

CODE:

```py
import boto3
import datetime
from tabulate import tabulate

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Set up the billing client
    client = boto3.client('ce', region_name='ap-south-1')

    # Set the start and end dates for the billing report
    start_date = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
    end_date = datetime.date.today()

    # Set the granularity for the report  
    granularity = 'DAILY'

    # Set the metric for the report
    metric = 'BlendedCost'

    # Set the group by parameter for the report
    group_by = [
        {
            'Type': 'DIMENSION',
            'Key': 'SERVICE'
        }
    ]

    # Get the billing report
    response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={
            'Start': start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            'End': end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        },
        Granularity=granularity,
        Metrics=[metric],
        GroupBy=group_by
    )

    # Parse the response to get service names and costs
    services = {}
    for result in response['ResultsByTime']:
        for group in result['Groups']:
            service_name = group['Keys'][0]
            cost = group['Metrics'][metric]['Amount']
            if service_name in services:
                services[service_name] += cost
            else:
                services[service_name] = cost

    # Create a table with the service names and their costs
    data = []
    for service_name, cost in services.items():
        data.append([service_name, cost])
    table = tabulate(data, headers=["Service", "Cost"], tablefmt="pretty")
    print(table)
    # Return the billing report as a response
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': table
    }
    return response
```

Comment: `AccessDeniedException` means that not all needed privileges is allowed inside IAM role

Answer (score 2):

`AccessDeniedException` means that your Lambda functions needs an IAM permission it does not have (or which is too restrictive in terms of concerned resources). As this is when calling `client.get_cost_and_usage()`, I expect it to be `ce:GetCostAndUsage` (you can see a complete liste [here](https://aws.permissions.cloud/iam/ce)).

Adding this to the execution role of your Lambda should solve the problem.

As a prerequisite of all this, you must have enabled Cost Explorer for your AWS account [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-enable.html).

Comment: Actually I am a IAM user of my company. So  attach a policy which contains this json code: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ce:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: It looks okay though a bit wide. Did you have a chance to check this is actually attached to the execution role of your lambda?

Comment: Yes I had attached this to my execution role. But the root user is my company account so may be its possible that they had some restriction for security purpose.

Comment: Something you can check is the SCP (service control policy) of the account. This is a policy that controls which services are available in this account. This comes with enabling Cost explorer, as seen at the end of my answer

Comment: I used it in other company AWS account and working fine but for one company account its not running. Still not got the perfect solution.